# Python: How to convert elapsed seconds to H:M:S format

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, strftime

I have this code:

```
start = time.time()

# some code here that doesn't have anything to do with the question

end = time.time()

time_result = int(end - start)
```

The `time_result` variable is the number of seconds it took to finish running the code. How would I convert this to a '00:00:00' string (hours, minutes and seconds)?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Sorry, I'm just confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC: To convert the number of elapsed seconds to a string such as `00:00:23`:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt

start = time.time()
elapsed = time.time() - start

# Edited to use UTC.
output = dt.strftime(dt.utcfromtimestamp(elapsed), '%H:%M:%S')

>>> '00:00:23'
```

Other formatting strings can be found here in the [datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Comment: I tried using this, it does work, but for some weird reason the hour is set to one, even though this just took 3 seconds to finish.

Comment: I'm using that exact mask, and the value of `elasped` is 3.6508941650390625.

Comment: Ah!  Try `dt.utcfromtimestamp` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
conversion = timedelta(seconds=time_result)
converted_time = str(conversion)
print(converted_time)
```

Comment: And If I undestood question correctly, this is exactly what author wants. strftime() converts date, time and datetime objects to its equivalent string. There is no date, time or datetime objects, only integer so i assumed that strftime() is pointless and output is exactly the same.

Comment: Please use the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68831763/edit) link under your answer to include all your explanations, descriptions, and comments. All the info should be part of the answer. The comments section here should only be for clarifications by other users.

Answer (score 0):

From the standard library

```
import datetime as dt

print(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time()))
```

Output

```
2021-08-18 14:05:44.232976
```

If you need only the date use `dt.date`

Here you can find the format codes, [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timezone-objects)

Comment: How would I put in my variable time_result using this method?

Comment: @HedTB instead of `time.time()` as shown in your attempt... just the difference of times that you are looking for

Comment: once you a dt object you can access to hours with the attribute `hour`, minute, seconds and so on